# How to run "if not" statement before "else":

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using Sqlite3 and Python. Here is some sample code:

```
       test
-----------------
   amount | date

query = "SELECT SUM (column1) FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN '"+blah+"' AND '"+blah+"'"
c.execute(query)
data = c.fetchone()
if not data:
   amountsum = 0
else:
   amountsum = data[0]

print(amountsum)
```

The problem is that it only runs else:. If data is NoneType it does not set amountsum to 0 either. How can I make this work?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible that `data` can be `None` here.

Comment: `if not data:` --> `if data is None:` This will handle the case where the query return no records.

Comment: @OliverAlmonte Did my suggestion solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `data` will never be `None`, due to the aggregating query. `SELECT SUM(...) FROM table` will always return exactly one row. However, the `SUM` can be `None` in SQLite, if there are no rows in the table, so that should be taken into account:

```
query = "SELECT SUM (column1) FROM test WHERE ..."
c.execute(query)
data = c.fetchone()
amount = data[0] or 0
```

(A sidenote: you seem to be creating your SQL query using string concatenation, which is a potential [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability. Consider using parameterized queries instead.)

Comment: So if no rows match the `WHERE` clause, the result would be `[None]`, am I correct? But the result would never be `None` or `[]`.

Comment: @FredLarson `fetchone()` will return `(None,)`. It's due to the aggregated query. If it was `SELECT * FROM table`, it would return `None`.